Get data from txt file
I have a .txt file with the following format:
{u'FirstName': u'Bob', u'LastName': u'Brown', u'Birthday': u'1989', u'Country': u'USA', u'Education': u'BA', u'Contract': u'Yes', u'Major': u'Maths', u'EmployeeStatus': u'Permanent', u'Department': u'Business'}

{u'FirstName': u'Jayden', u'LastName': u'Chan', u'Birthday': u'1995', u'Country': u'China', u'Education': u'BA', u'Contract': u'Yes', u'Major': u'Business', u'EmployeeStatus': u'Contract', u'Department': u'Business'}

I need to extract FirstName, LastName, Department and put the info into a new .txt file in the form of row and column.
I am thinking of using read_csv() to change it to dataframe and the change back to text file, but the result is not as expected:



u'FirstName'
Bob
u'LastName'
Brown
u'Department'
Business




u'FirstName'
Jayden
u'LastName'
Chan
u'Department'
Business



Please help with this.

It's a Python dictionary literal. You could use ast.literal_eval to parse it into a dictionary and then create your new file from that.

"I am thinking of using read_csv() to change it to dataframe and the change back to text file, but the result is not as expected:" - what do you expect that the result should be instead, and how is that different? "Please help with this. Thank you." - please keep in mind that it is not possible to "help you" here as this is not a discussion forum. We require a specific question that is focused on the exact thing that you need to know in order to solve the problem.

df = pd.DataFrame(eval(a), index=[0])
